# dynamically specifying DataTable columns

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, casting

I have a `object[,] myObj`. I also have `string[] fieldTypes`. I want to get the data from my object array into a DataTable.

I want the DataTable columns though to be of the correct type, i.e. `string`, `datetime`, `double` etc. This is where the `fieldTypes` array comes in.

So let me start with a basic example:

`myObj` has n rows and 3 columns. `fieldTypes` will be an array of length 3 (i.e. the same number of columns as `myObj`)

Let's say my

```
 fieldTypes = {'string', 'DateTime', 'double' }
```

Is there a way to setup up my `DataTable` to have correct columns using the `fieldTypes`?

Something like below (I know what I have written below is incorrect)

```
DateTable dt = new DataTable();
for(int i=0; i < fieldTypes.Length; i++)
{
   dt.Columns.Add(myColName, typeof(fieldTypes[i]));
}
```

I would then need to cast the values in `myObj` so they could be added to my `DataTable`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have column names and types specified. Considering you already mapped type names to types.

I'd use a column specification class like:

```
class ColSpec
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a jagged array instead of a multidimensional one, lets you add rows easier, no cast required.

```
var colspecs = new ColSpec[] { 
    new ColSpec { Type = typeof(int), Name = "int" }, 
    new ColSpec { Type = typeof(string), Name = "string" } };
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange (colspecs.Select(x=> new DataColumn(x.Name, x.Type) ).ToArray()) ;
// single row jagged array 
object[][] myObj = new object[1][];
// 2 colums per row
myObj[0] = new object[2] {100, "string"};
foreach (object[] objs in myObj)
    dt.Rows.Add(objs);
```